# pandas calculations on a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, percentage

using the dataframe code at this link https://pastebin.com/d1aW7u5N

I grouped it like this `df.groupby([col, 'win']).count()` to achieve this output
[image: desc]

But I want to have it be for every `death`, display the percentage of win/(win+loss) (basically show the win percentage) using the match id

For example, the end dataframe would look as such:

```
(deaths, percentage),  
(0, 1) because 9 wins and 0 losses for deaths=0  
(1, .77) because 7 wins and 2 losses for deaths=1 and 7/(7+2) = .77  
(2, .84) because 21 wins and 4 losses for deaths=2 and 21/(21+4) = .84  
(3, .74) ...
```

Problem: I want to display the winrates per deaths as outlined above, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was my final answer that allowed me to see the winrates (percentage within each group) for all values

```
df = df.groupby([col, 'win']).count().reset_index().pivot('deaths', 'win', 'matchID').fillna(0)
df['winrate'] = (df[1] / (df[1] + df[0]))
df.columns.name = None
df = df.drop([0, 1], axis=1)
df
```

Comment: Please, consider `df.fillna(0)` write in the end of the first line instead of the second and third line that you have now.

Comment: @Alex I need an np.nan in the 0 column to convert to a 0 and a np.nan in the 1 column to convert to a 1

Comment: Your line 3 doesn't seem to do that, does it? I don't see the reason why you would want to do that: specifically converting np.nan to 1 in the column 1.

Comment: because a null in the 1 column means that at that particular deaths, there were no games won. The 1 column represents wins and the 0 column represents losses

Comment: You say "at that particular deaths, there were no games won". Exactly, so why do you want to assign 1 win when there wasn't any?

Comment: You are actually so correct, thank you for noticing that!